# Creating a 3x3 with text in Python

Tags: python, loops

I understand there has been a range of other posts relating to this however I am looking for a simplistic way to form a 3x3 grid in Python from words loaded from a text file.

So I am loading my words from a text file using:

```
file = open("words.txt","r").readlines()
```

and attempting to have them printed in a form such as:

```
Cat Dog Fish
Log Mouse Rat
Horse Cow Meow
```

Ideally I tried using a for-loop but couldn't figure out how to add the \n after three prints.

Comment: Your example is neither formatted nor a 3x3 but a 3x2 (or 2x3).

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to add the final set.

Comment: Final set is Horse Cow Meow

Comment: More importantly, how does the words.txt file look like?

Comment: As Stephan said, you should tell us the format of your input text file. Specifically, does it have one word per line? Also, does it only have 9 words in it? Also, it's best to avoid using `file` as a variable name, since in Python 2 it's a built-in type, like `list`, `str`, `dict`, etc, and using such things as variable names can cause annoying & mysterious bugs. It's safe to use `file` for your own variables in Python 3, but it's still probably not good stylistically.

Answer (score 2):

Use a counter to add a new line when necessary:

```
for num, word in enumerate(file, 1):
    print word.strip(),
    if num % 3 == 0:
        print
```

Ideally, the best way to read lines from a file is not to read them all into one list (unless you explicitly need them like that), and to use a context manager to ensure the file gets closed properly:

```
with open('words.txt', 'r') as f:
    for num, word in enumerate(f, 1):
        print word.strip(),
        if num % 3 == 0:
            print
```

Comment: FWIW, `enumerate()` can take a 2nd argument, the `start` parameter, so you can get it to start counting from any number you like, rather than zero. Using `enumerate(f, 1)` would simplify your logic a little: you could do `if num % 3 == 0:` after printing the word.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate) module

```
from tabulate import tabulate
f = open("words.txt","r").readlines()

words = list(map(str.split, f))
print tabulate(words)
```

Output:

```
In [18]: print tabulate(words)
---  -----  ----
Cat  Dog    Fish
Log  Mouse  Rat
Foo  Bar    Baz
---  -----  ----
```

But if you have one word per line in your words.txt.Then this should work:

```
from tabulate import tabulate
f = open("words.txt","r").readlines()
f1=[f[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(f),3)]
print tabulate(f1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your file contains one word per line:

```
lines = open("words.txt","r").readlines()
words = list(map(str.strip, lines))
for i in range(0, 9, 3):
    print(' '.join(words[i:i+3]))
```

First I read the lines like you do, then I remove the trailing newlines to just get the words, then I walk over the list in steps of 3, and print each triple joined by space.

Answer (score 0):

After all, you just want to add enough spaces to have each word of each row aligned, but just the least spaces possible. Similarly, each line must be aligned, but that's not a problem.

To complete with spaces, you must at first find what is the biggest word of the row. Then, you could define what row width you want. With this width, you'll be able to add the missing spaces for each word.

Let's assume your words are stocked in a two dimensional list: `words_list = [[Cat, Dog, Fish], [Log, Mouse, Rat]]`.

We'll assume that every sub-lists have the same length. You must now find the biggest word of each row. For this, we'll iterate on the words, and find the biggest one:

```
# This list contains the maximum width of the row
# We set it to [0, 0, ..., 0] to start (in fact, no length will
# be negative)
# Every sublist have the same length = len(list1)
widths = [0 for i in range len(words_list[1])]

# Now, we'll iterate on the lines, and find the biggest width
for line in words_list:
    for biggest, word in zip(widths, line):
        # check if this word will expand the row
        if len(word) > biggest:
            biggest = len(word)
```

Now, widths contains the maximum length of each row. Now, let's print them. Notice that we must add 1 to each maximum width, else there will be some mistakes.

```
for line in words_list:
    text_line = ""
    for length, word in zip(widths, line):
        text_line += word
        text_line += " " * (length - len(word) + 1)
    print(text_line)
```

Comment: From the example output shown in the question it does _not_ appear that Reece needs the columns to be aligned... but  guess it doesn't hurt. OTOH, I _suspect_ that at this stage they may not know how to read their text file into a 2D list.